# getting localised string

Tags: c, localization, gnome

I have created a localized **fr_FR_Locale.mo** files from **fr_FR.po**.

I have used *sgettext*, *msginit* and *msgfmt* command from terminal.

I have changed my local to **french(fr_FR.utf8)**.

But when i execute my code i am not getting what i am expecting. Here is my call:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
bindtextdomain("locale",LC_INTL);
bind_textdomain_codeset("locale", "UTF-8");
textdomain("locale");
printf(gettext("Hello world!"));
```

Here the output should be some thing **non english**, 
    but i am getting same **English words**.

Comment: Can we see your `gettext()` function?

Comment: @marcog: I am using the following headers:                   #include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>

Comment: Could it have anything to do with using the wrong form of the encoding name (`utf8` instead of `UTF-8`) in the locale name string?

Comment: Nope it does not make any change...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your mo-file isn't found. I don't know what LC_INTL means or where you installed your mo-file. But let's say you installed it as `/usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/MyApp.mo`, the code should look like:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
bindtextdomain("MyApp","/usr/local/share/locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("MyApp","UTF-8");
textdomain("MyApp");
```